# Carrierwave - Resizing images to fixed width

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rmagick, carrierwave

I'm using RMagick and want my images to be resized to a fixed width of 100px, and scale the height proportionally.  For example, if a user were to upload a 300x900px, I would like it to be scaled to 100x300px.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Just put this in your uploader file:

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  version :resized do
    # returns an image with a maximum width of 100px 
    # while maintaining the aspect ratio
    # 10000 is used to tell CW that the height is free 
    # and so that it will hit the 100 px width first
    process :resize_to_fit => [100, 10000]
  end

end
```

Documentation and example here: http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html#resize_to_fit

Keep in mind, `resize_to_fit` will scale up images if they are smaller than 100px.  If you don't want it to do that, then replace that with `resize_to_limit`.

Comment: as pointed out by Giang Nguyen: with regards to carrierwave and image processing, `[100, nil]` seems to be equivalent to `[100, 100]`!

Answer (score 15):

I use

```
process :resize_to_fit => [100, 10000]
```

Use `10000` or any very big number to let Carrierwave know the height is free, just resize to the width.

@iWasRobbed: I don't think that's the correct solution. According to the link you pasted about `resize_to_fit`: `The maximum height of the resized image. If omitted it defaults to the value of new_width.` So in your case `process :resize_to_fit => [100, nil]` is equivalent to `process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]` which doesn't guarantee that you will always get the fixed width of 100px

Answer (score 13):

Wouldn't a better solution actually be:

```
process :resize_to_fit => [100, -1]
```

This way you don't have to limit height at all

EDIT: Just realized this only works with MiniMagick, For RMagick you seem to have no option but to add a large number to the height

Comment: Note that `[-1, 100]` would not work, meaning you can't create fixed height image thumbnails.