# Load thumbnails image quickly

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, carrierwave

I have a web app that will show gallery of thumbnails. My problem is, some images are very huge (like 6000 x 6000), and my current approach is load the image into image tag, then use css to set max-width and max-height, which is very slow because of the huge image loaded behind.

What is the easiest solution for this situation?

I am using Rails, and the images are uploaded using Carrierwave.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try looking at the [image thumbnails section](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave#adding-versions) on the Carrierwave github page. The idea is that when a large image is uploaded, you can resize the image and store a copy of it. Later on, you can then serve a smaller version of the image to make the request times much faster.

You may also want to keep the proper aspect ratio in the image uploaded by using `0` or `nil` as the width or height you want to be dependent on the other attribute. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194421/rails-3-0-carrierwave-and-resize-to-a-specific-width) for more information.

Comment: Yep making a smaller copy is best way to go. For big pics like that I would also try to move resizing into background process using `carrierwave_backgrounder`gem.